# How to turning off logging for certain postgres function calls

Tags: postgresql

I have a couple of functions (`login`, `reset-password`) implemented as functions. Is it possible to make sure that these functions are not logged by either postgres itself or any extensions that may be installed?

Comment: Look at the `set` clause of the `create function` statement and `track_*` and `log_*` options.

Comment: I took at look at that. I don't know that the granularity of the track_* and log_* functions can be controlled to specific functions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot absolutely eliminate the possibility of logging parameters.  Your log files should only be readable by people you really trust (generally the same people who have superuser on the database).  Also, you might consider reading the salt and hash from the database and doing the rehashing and comparison in the app server, rather than sending the password in the clear to the database.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid an appserver altogether and would like to explore all options.

Comment: What does a login function do in the absence of an app server?  In order to execute that function, they must have already logged on to the database.

Comment: well.. technically yes. there has to be a bridging server between the db and a client that passes client requests to the db but I'd like it to be as lightweight as possible and for most of the logic to sit on the db. If it's not secure to do so, then I'd just go the standard way.